# Google API auth via service key succeeds, but still gets "401 Login Required" on subsequent requests

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using the service key method to authenticate with googleapis in node.js. I can authenticate successfully, but when I try to make a request after that I get a "401 Login Required" error.

Here is the authentication code:

```
const google = require('googleapis').google;
const privateKey = require('./private_key.json');

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    privateKey.client_email,
    null,
    privateKey.private_key,
    [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
    ]
);

jwtClient.authorize((err, tokens) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Google Authenticated');
    }
});
```

In the above code, the "Google Authenticated" text is shown successfully, indicating authentication should have succeeded.

But when I try to use the API after that, I get a 401 error back from this:

```
google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get({
    auth: jwtClient,
    ids: 'ga:xxxxxxxx',
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews'
}).then((err, result) => {
    // error object here contains a 401
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up callbacks and promises :) Give this a try!

```js
google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get({
    auth: jwtClient,
    ids: 'ga:xxxxxxxx',
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews'
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result.data);
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Can you give that a try?